# MS Access Table with Multiple foreign keys to same table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table in MS Access that has 4 columns in it and they all contain an id that is the primary key in another table and I want to know if there is another way to do this and if not how can I get Access to let me join on these without the error that it can't tell what I am trying to join on.  Pretty much these id's are part of a student table and they contain ids for their supervisor for that block and there are 4 blocks and I need to be able to track what students each supervisor had for each block.

**Supervisor Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE supervisors 
( id NUMBER primary key
, last_name TEXT
, first_name TEXT
, mi TEXT
, m_number TEXT
, email HYPERLINK
, status TEXT
, notes MEMO
) ;
```

**Student Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE students 
( id NUMBER primary key
, last_name TEXT
, first_name TEXT
, mi TEXT
, m_number TEXT
, email HYPERLINK
, blk1_supervisor_id NUMBER
, blk2_supervisor_id NUMBER
, blk3_supervisor_id NUMBER
, blk4_supervisor_id NUMBER
) ;
```

I can't get it to let me make the blk1, 2, 3, 4 fields foreign keys to the supervisor table let alone do a join on say blk1_supervisor_id and blk2_supervisor_id at the same time.

Comment: Please post a description of your table with column names.  Thanks

Comment: Is there another way to do what? Your problem isn't quite clear to me, pleas clarify your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your Supervisors table as it is now, have a Students table that has only true Student properties (down to email). then you create a StudentsSupervisor relationship table:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentsSupervisors 
( StudentId NUMBER 
  SupervisorId Number )
```

where both fields constitute the PK. If you NEED to identify further the relationship, you coudl add the `blockNumber` to that table, and eventually include it in the PK if the same SuperVisor can be linked to the same Student twice in different blocks.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  That is what I needed to know and yes I will have to add the block number as the same supervisor can be linked to the same student multiple times in different blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your table schema, this is the best I can do for you...

```
SELECT SV.Name, S.Name, SB.Block
FROM Students as S

   INNER JOIN Student_Blocks AS SB
   ON S.StudentID = SB.StudentID

   INNER JOIN Supervisors AS SV
   ON SB.Block1SupervisorID = SV.SupervisorID
   AND SB.Block2SupervisorID = SV.SupervisorID
   AND SB.Block3SupervisorID = SV.SupervisorID
   AND SB.Block4SupervisorID = SV.SupervisorID

ORDER BY SB.Block
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick and easy way to normalise your tables correctly. Choose one option from each statement below.
A student can have none/one/many supervisors.
A supervisor can have none/one/many students.
In your case, a student can have many supervisors and a supervisor can have many students. The relationship between students and supervisors is thus many-many, which is not allowed in a RDBMS. In such circumstances you must create a join table between the two, as Patrick Honorez has shown you.